# 301 htaccess redirects with numbers in URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect using 301 htaccess redirects the following URL

http://domain.com/vb/thread1023.html

to

http://domain.com/forum/threads/1023/

The 1023 is just a variable and the code must work with any number

To be specific I am converting a website from one software to another and the URL structures are different.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work just fine given that mod_rewrite is enable and working:

```
RewriteRule ^vb/thread(\d+)\.html$ /forum/threads/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

The left hand of the rule `^vb/thread(\d+)\.html$` captures the numbers that comes after `thread` and before `.html`.

The left side of the rule `/forum/threads/$1/` redirects the URL adding at the end in place of `$1` the captured number.

For the URL you mentioned on the the comment `http://www.domain.com/vb/showthread.php?t=1023`

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^t=(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^vb/showthread\.php$ /forum/threads/%1/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: It's not working. I need the code to force the visitors to be redirected to the new URL and not creating another URL for the same content. I am using cPanel and mod_rewrite is enabled.

Comment: @Khaleal This does not create a new URL it redirects the user as You have mentioned. If you have more rules on your htaccess file it may cause this rule not to work so post your htaccess.

Comment: It's working now. I had to remove the original .htaccess file which was used to rewrite the php files of the old software to .html. Thank you :)

Comment: BTW, What if the old URL was http://www.domain.com/vb/showthread.php?t=1023 ? Thanks in advance.